# Can I say I am C2 if I passed C1 Advanced with an A?

Tags: learning, pedagogy

Cambridge English Scale asserts that, although the exam is targeted at Level C1 of the CEFR, it also provides reliable assessment at the level above C1 (Level C2). See [here](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-tests/advanced/results/).

The Statement of Results also specifies it:

> "Candidates achieving Grade A (between 200 and 210 on the Cambridge
>   English Scale) receive the Certificate in Advanced English stating
>   that they have demonstrated ability at Level C2"

I usually state that I am C2 in my CV, but I want to know to what extent is this a valid official certificate or if I should take an exam targeted at C2.

Comment: "Valid" for what purpose? A certificate is a certificate, nothing more, nothing less. Whether someone will accept it for a particular purpose is up to them. It sounds to me like you have simply stated a demonstrable fact on your CV and there's clearly nothing wrong with that.

Comment: This might be a "meta" ELL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that means is that you are *likely* to pass the C2 exam, not that you *have*. So, no. Your only certification is C1.

You could say you believe you have a C2-level of proficiency, but nothing beyond that.

However, there's certainly nothing wrong with stating *passed C1 Advanced with an A*, and letting others interpret that how they wish.